# Spring Boot mongoDB Aggregation return empty data

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework

I have a problem to filter the mongoDB data. Here is the data:

```
{
   "name":"Macbook Pro",
   "category":"Apple",
   "productId":"X90fD0uD8MsBoc4",
   "details":{
      "rating":"5",
      "stocks":"10",
      "price":"null",
      "tags":[
         {
            "tags1":"apple",
            "tags2":"macbook",
            "tags3":null
         }
      ],
      "brand":"Apple",
      "description":"null",
      "picture":[
         {
            "picture1":"photo1",
            "picture2":"photo2",
            "picture3":"photo 3",
            "picture4":null,
            "picture5":null
         }
      ],
      "thumbnails":[
         {
            "thumbnail1":"thumbails1",
            "thumbnail2":"thumbails2",
            "thumbnail3":null,
            "thumbnail4":null,
            "thumbnail5":null
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Now when I try to filter it with this code:

```
final Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.match(
        Criteria.where("name").regex(query, "i").and("details").elemMatch(
            Criteria.where("brand").regex(query, "i"))
        ),
    Aggregation.skip(page * pageable.getPageSize()),
    Aggregation.limit(pageable.getPageSize())
);
List<Products> filter = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "Product", Products.class).getMappedResults();
return new PageImpl<Products>(filter, pageable, filter.size())
```

The result is an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason you are getting an empty array as a result is the match operation. You are telling mongo you want regex match on both the name field AND the details.brand field using the same string, query. So if you search for "mac" the name field gets found but not the brand field and vice-versa for a search on "apple". Consider using an OrOperator.

Something like this:

```
Aggregation.match( Criteria.orOperator( Criteria.where( "name" ).regex( query, "i" ), Criteria.where( "details.brand" ).regex( query, "i" ) ) )
```